# Changing the Header information of a html page programmatically

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ipad, uiwebview

I am currently displaying an HTML page in to my `UIWebView`(iPad) and it is loading properly.

But the problem is, it is not properly fit into my container view. So I have tried everything like scalePageToFit..etc but it does not fulfill my requirement.

So I have checked the HTML page and it displays like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
.....
......
</html>
```

So after googling a bit i find out that we can insert any java script file (by using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`) to our html file
and can do anything.

So can I change the following:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

to this?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will work on iPhone, but to add a meta tag using Javascript, you would use soemthing like this:

```
var meta;
if (document.createElement && (meta = document.createElement('meta'))) {
    meta.name = "viewport";
    meta.content = "width=320";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(meta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apple tech note “Preparing Your Web Content for iPad” has a good suggestion: avoid hard-coding a width for your viewport. On the iPad, a viewport width smaller than 1024 can cause your content to be blown up and blurred. Their suggestion is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This is an improvement, but your content will still be blown up if your device is in landscape mode. This is because device-width is the width of the physical device (320px or 768px), not the width of the screen in the current orientation. As a consequence, you can get content rendered at 768px and blown up to 1024px.

Avoiding Blowup

To make sure your content is not blown up, set the maximum-scale to 1.0:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720,
                           maximum-scale=1.0" />
```